# how do i place text opposite to Anchor Tag Using CSS

Tags: html, css

please help.....

how do i place text opposite to Anchor Tag in HTML, please check below markup

```html
<a href="#">Business</a> Software
```

please check with image below

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Can you improve your question Hrshad and try to be more accurate? Take a look at other questions, maybe read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` and `float: left;` to`.cat-post-item a, .cat-post-widget h2 a, .cat-item a`. Then move `text-align:`<s>left</s>`right;` to the parent: `.sidebar li`.

So you should have:

```
.cat-post-item a, .cat-post-widget h2 a, .cat-item a {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
```

and

```
.sidebar li {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: u can check with link http://equigreen.in/blog/index.php/category/business/

i tried above but it is not working

Comment: What's wrong about it?

Comment: also i want to move count on right side and text to left :)

Comment: Wrap each of the "(1)"'s and what not in `<p>` tags and then use float.

Comment: Yes your answer worked but, i want to move count on right side and text to left :)

Comment: Yes then do what I just suggested and let me know if that works.

Comment: yes u right ... but i don't have access to elements, they are generating dynamically :)

Comment: Oh okay, see if this answer works for you.

Comment: Thank you Jaunt .... for your best support... IT WORKs !!! DUDE